# How to fill right in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

Perhaps I missed this in the documentation but can Anyone point Me in the direction of how to fill right a series of columns in emacs's org-mode? I believe I saw how to fill down but do not recall seeing how to fill right.

Edit: For example, I am looking for a way to take:

| 8 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 9 |

| :=@1$1*2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And turn it into:

| 8 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 9 |

| :=@1$1*2 | :=@1$2*2 | :=@1$3*2 | :=@1$4*2 | :=@1$5*2 | :=@1$6*2 | :=@1$7*2 |

Which evaluates to:

| 16 | 12 | 14 | 10 | 6 | 0 | 18 |

Comment: Please provide two files: one with sample state, the other with the state that you want after the command.

Comment: @abo-abo: example is now available

Comment: So you just need this formula `@2$1..@2$>=@1*2`?

Comment: @abo-abo: Thanks, I just tried it and it didn't work, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with this state:

```
| 8 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 9 |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
#+TBLFM: @2=@1*2
```

You get to this state:

```
|  8 |  6 |  7 |  5 | 3 | 0 |  9 |
| 16 | 12 | 14 | 10 | 6 | 0 | 18 |
#+TBLFM: @2=@1*2
```

by pressing <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> while on the line with `TBLFM`.

Comment: No, I don't get that result.